# There is one application running on java 1.8 (only), which version of Jenkins can be used to run scripts from pipeline?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, compatibility

I need to run selenium scripts developed bsed on java 1.8, using Jenkins pipeline. Which jenkins version can be used to build pipeline so that automation scripts developed on java 1.8 can run?

tried using jenkins version 2.251 but it's not allowing me to chose my code base location !

Comment: Any I think? You might not want to rely on (just) Jenkins; You are allowed to integrate with Docker or Kubernetes, this enables you to use specific build images for specific cases. Sources: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/ & https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a node with java8 as jenkins slave, and run selenium scripts on that node.

Or you can run it in docker container with java 8, see
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/